# GIT Attach repo in other repo

Tags: git, bitbucket

I use GIT on bitbucket.org. I have 2 repositories; first repository is *repo1* and has only one file (`ui.css`), but second repository (*repo2*) is the full app.

Directory and files schema in *repo2*:

```
index.html
js/
js/jquery-custom.js
css/
css/styles.css
img/
img/...
```

Now I would like import from *repo1* (only one file) to `css/` directory in *repo2*.

After that, I'll have two files in directory `css/` in my *repo2* (`styles.css` and `ui.css`), but I would like as well when I change the file in *repo1* (file `ui.css`) the changes should be also in *repo2*.

Comment: Have you looked into `git-submodules`? http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: Yes, but I had a problem with overwriting directory `css/`...

Comment: You probably need to put that repo1/css in it's own directory and update your include paths. if that is not possible, then making the tie in of single files across git repos is probably not going to work.

Comment: Do you want to merge the repositories just once and be done with it or do you expect later changes in `repo1`? The first case has an easy solution, the second gets messy since you already made a mess.

Comment: I would like change `ui.css` only in *repo1* but always should be actualy in *repo2*

Comment: Nobody know solution. Submodule works only with directories not files.